Spring boot web app with jsp error no mapping for GET
I am dealing with a problem


Here is my EmployeeController:
EmployeeController
package com.examenjsp.jsp.controllers;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

import com.examenjsp.jsp.jdbcConnect;


@Controller
@EnableWebMvc
@RequestMapping("/views") // Applies to all routes within this controller
public class EmployeeController {


    @GetMapping({"/", "/index"})
    public String showIndex(Model model) {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM employees";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employeesdb";
        String name = "root";
        String password = "rootadmin223";
        String table = jdbcConnect.GetTable(query, url, name, password);
        model.addAttribute("employeeTable", table);
        return "index"; // 
    }


    @PostMapping("/action_page")
    public String addEmployee(
            @RequestParam("first_name") String firstName,
            @RequestParam("last_name") String lastName,
            @RequestParam("salary_pm") float salaryPm,
            @RequestParam("hire_date") String hireDate,
            @RequestParam("company") String company,
            @RequestParam("department") String department) {

        jdbcConnect.addValue(firstName, lastName, salaryPm, hireDate, company, department);
        return "redirect:/views/index"; // Redirects back to index after adding
    }


    @PostMapping("/edit_employee")
    public String editEmployee(@RequestParam("employee_id") int employeeId, Model model) {
        try {
            ResultSet rs = jdbcConnect.getValue(employeeId);
            if (rs != null && rs.next()) {
                model.addAttribute("employeeId", employeeId);
                model.addAttribute("firstName", rs.getString("first_name"));
                model.addAttribute("lastName", rs.getString("last_name"));
                model.addAttribute("salaryPm", rs.getFloat("salary_pm"));
                model.addAttribute("hireDate", rs.getString("hire_date"));
                model.addAttribute("company", rs.getString("company"));
                model.addAttribute("department", rs.getString("department"));
                return "edit_employee"; // Shows edit_employee.jsp
            } else {
                model.addAttribute("error", "Employee not found");
                return "error"; // Shows an error page if employee isn't found
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            model.addAttribute("error", "Error occurred while fetching employee details: " + e.getMessage());
            return "error"; // Shows an error page on SQL exceptions
        }
    }

    // PostMapping to update an employee's details
    @PostMapping("/update_employee")
    public String updateEmployee(
            @RequestParam("employee_id") int employeeId,
            @RequestParam("first_name") String firstName,
            @RequestParam("last_name") String lastName,
            @RequestParam("salary_pm") float salaryPm,
            @RequestParam("hire_date") String hireDate,
            @RequestParam("company") String company,
            @RequestParam("department") String department) {

        jdbcConnect.setValue(employeeId, firstName, lastName, salaryPm, hireDate, company, department);
        return "redirect:/views/index"; // Redirects back to index after updating
    }

    // PostMapping to delete an employee
    @PostMapping("/delete_employee")
    public String deleteEmployee(@RequestParam("employee_id") int employeeId) {
        jdbcConnect.dropValue(employeeId);
        return "redirect:/views/index"; // Redirects back to index after deleting
    }
}

and here is my ExamenJspSpringApplication:
ExamenJspSpringApplication
package com.examenjsp.jsp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan.Filter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewResolverRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@EnableWebMvc
@SpringBootApplication()
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.examenjsp.jsp", "com.examenjsp.jsp.configuration","com.examenjsp.jsp.controllers"}, excludeFilters = { @Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = Configuration.class) })

public class ExamenJspSpringApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ExamenJspSpringApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests.anyRequest()
          .permitAll())
          .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
        return http.build();
    }
    
     
     
    
}

and here is my app structure:

The dependencies in my pom seem to be in place and my application.properties looks like this:
application.properties
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
server.port=8082
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employeesdb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=rootadmin223
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

What can I try to solve this?

Remove @EnableWebMvc that disables auto configuration.

Which url are you trying to get to? @RequestMapping("/views") will prefix all urls with "/views", your error message shows an attempt to access "/"

class EmployeeController Remove @EnableWebMvc and  @RequestMapping("/views")

Ok I will try to do that after a couple of hours when i'll be free and let you know. Thank yall a lot!

Update I have deleted the @EnableWebMvc and @RequestMapping("/views") and now I get an error 500 with the message: "jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'index' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'"

Spring can't find index.jsp. The way application.properties is set up, it's searching in /src/main/WEB-INF/views
